# what kind of list is good for notifications

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, pages, notifications

I need to setup a webpart (SharePoint-online) which displays notifications (not news containing only short text 100 characters) from a list (or Pages).

These notifications are a mixed of personlised and non-personlised notifications.

1. Non-personified notifications: Non-personlised notifications will be aggregated notifications from a hierarchy of Groups or Sites that the user belongs to. These notifications are visible for all members of the groups (or Sites).
2. Personified notificiations: The personlised notifications are those that only the user that the notification is assigned to, not other members of the Groups or Sites.
3. When the user read the notification (Click on them) they must be marked as "Read" (gray).

What is the best approach (Archecture) to solve this? Pages? lists? Sites? MS groups?